# Multiple cases - Testing based on ranges of values rather than single values in Java?

Tags: java, switch-statement, range, control-flow

As part of learning to write Java I found on the web the [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement for multiple cases.

The problem for me with this statement is that it compares the argument to the single numbers that I use as `case`s, but what if I want to differentiate the flow based on the range of values the argument belongs to?

Is there a more elegant way than using a lot of `if`s? I am looking for something like the [`cond`](https://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~rms/classes/cs275/labs/lab1/lab1a.html) statement in [Scheme](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/schemedoc/).

```java
public class Assignment02Q03 {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      int grade = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      if (grade >= 90) {
         System.out.println("A");
      } else {
         if (grade >= 80 ){
            System.out.println("B");
         } else {
            if (grade >= 70){
               System.out.println("C");
            }else {
               if (grade >= 60){
                  System.out.println("D");
               }else { 
                  System.out.println("F");
               }
            }
         }  
      } 
   }
}
```

There must be something more elegant :)

Thank you!

Comment: could you show an example of a code snippet you don't like and what you would like it to look like?

Comment: Sure Ramy, I'll finish writing the code this way and I'll edit my question afterwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally written as:

```
if (grade >= 90) {
    System.out.println("A");
} else if (grade>=80 ) {
    System.out.println("B");
} else if (grade>=70) {
    System.out.println("C");
} else if (grade>=60) {
    System.out.println("D");
} else { 
    System.out.println("F");
}
```

Not that there is anything special about `else if`. The braces can be replaced by a single statement, in this an `if`-`else` statement. The indentation is like nothing else in the language, but it's an idiom that should be easy to follow.

For an expression, there is also the ternary operator:

```
System.out.println(
    grade>=90 ? "A" :
    grade>=80 ? "B" :
    grade>=70 ? "C" :
    grade>=60 ? "D" :
    "F"
);
```

Answer (score 5):

In `Java` there are the `ifs`, `switch case` construct and `ternary operator`(which is a shortened `if`). Nothing elegant I guess:)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built into the language. For terse and quick code, you can create a Map that maps your test values to `Runnable` or `Callable` actions. However, that tends to be a little opaque because you have to look elsewhere in your code for info on what's in the map.

Comment: +1. I think it's right way to reflect many conditionals expressions to Java. But it should be `LinkedHashMap`, as order matter.

Comment: @Stas - Of course, you are right that test order sometimes matters. I hadn't thought about that. They often don't matter (when the tests are mutually exclusive, like in a switch with no fall-through), but when the order does matter, the tests would have to be rewritten to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Of course in real cases order mostly doesn't matters. BUT in Schemes `cond` it metters)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (a > b) 
{
  max = a;
}
else 
{
  max = b;
}
```

can be written like this....

```
max = (a > b) ? a : b;
```

Comment: Don't you mean 'can be written'?

Answer (score 1):

Like many other languages you may use a ternary if-test.

```
String text = (1 < 10) ? "One is not greater than ten!" : "One is greater than ten";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is OOP and polymorphism in Java)
You can write smt like

```
 ActionFactory.create(grade).execute()

 //returns some instance
 public static AbstractAction create(int grade){
      //can be based on Maps as @Ted Hopp mentioned
      if(grade >= 0){
           return new PositiveAction();
      } else {
           return new NegativeAction();
      }
 }
 //can be interface
 class AbstractAction{
     public abstract void execute();
 }
 class PositiveAction extends AbstractAction {
     public void execute(){Sout("positive");}
 }
 class NegativeAction extends AbstractAction {
     public void execute(){Sout("negative");}
 }
```

It seems more verbose, but it works in real tasks. Java isn't for elegant solutions. Java for work. Feel Java)